# Valid vs Invalid dismissals of Community flags

Tags: discussion, flags, community-user, moderator-tools

When dismissing an automated flag from the Community user, is my choice of Valid vs Invalid taken into consideration by the automated flagging algorithm?

In other words, does my Valid vs Invalid selection affect which posts will be flagged in the future by the automated "low quality post" process, or just the weights of those flags?

Comment: To my expectation, it'll only influence the order of the flags in comparison to other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When dismissing an automated flag from the Community user, is my choice of Valid vs Invalid taken into consideration by the automated flagging algorithm?

While I cannot find any clear reference, past posts about this system suggest that the heuristics it uses to determine what to flag and what not to flag are not adaptive.  They don't change without someone going in and changing the code.

More specifically, choosing valid or invalid does not change what is and is not flagged by this process.  As Jeff indicates it does change the weight this process's flags are given compared to other flag events.  It is hopefully subject to the same system that notifies moderators if a user is consistently flagging things that shouldn't be, which would then be a sign that the process code needs to be adjusted.

Comment: s/flags is given/flags are given

Comment: @BenV - Edit away!

Answer (score 2):

Invalid means the flag is **invalid**, that the user flagged something **incorrectly**.

This reduces their future flag weight.

Community user, however, is immune to the effects of flag weight sorting.

Comment: How does this apply to the **Community** user?

Comment: @ChrisF It would become depressed after many invalid dismisses and finally stop poking old questions.

Comment: So valid vs invalid doesn't affect which answers will be flagged by the automated "low quality post" process, it just affects the weights of those flags, correct?

Comment: @BenV - I gather from various posts about this automated process that it is not adaptive - that is, it requires development time to change its heuristics.  So no, it won't change which posts will be flagged.

Comment: @Pollyanna: That's exactly what I was asking.  Can you put that in an answer?

Comment: @chris it doesn't, community is immune to flag weight sorting